# Can I use MongoDB schema model for defining IndexedDB indexes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb, mongoose-schema

I am creating a progressive web app that that is using NodeJS and Express as backend, MongoDB as server, and IndexedDB for storing data locally when offline.

Currently I have defined some Mongoose schema models, and my application is suppose to fetch the data from my MongoDB server and store it into my local IndexedDB when the application goes online. Is it possible to make my IndexedDB's indexes follow the format of my Mongoose schema models, so that if I made some changes to the models, the IndexedDB's indexes will follow the changes as well.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not so clear, an example would have help. But from what I understand, you want to be able to change the schema in MongoDB without breaking the documents saved in IndexedDB and you don't want to update the schema in IndexedDB each time you change the schema in MongoDB. You could use PouchDB which can use IndexedDB behind the scene and it would you to match the same schema as in your MongoDB. PouchDB integrates very well with MongoDB. Thus, if you model changes in MongoDB, when the document is eventually saved on PouchDB (IndexedDB), the document would have the same schema! For your info, PouchDB is the equivalent of MongoDB but in a browser.